# What happens to my 3d model when I apply the mirror modifier ? it adds extra vertices

Tags: modeling, vertices, mirror

I don't understand what happens to my 3d model when I apply the mirror modifier. It seems that it adds a lot of vertices that I can't remove anymore. Anyway the modifier is able to mirror the eye socket correctly. Check the pictures attached and help me to understand how to fix the problem. Thanks.

[image: before applying the mirror modifier]

[image: after applying the mirror modifier]

[image: extra vertices view]

[image: here you can see that the eye has been mirrored succesfully]

Comment: What are the 3 meshes?  One is not visible except at render.  Do you have two copies of the Bird?  Examine this by clicking objects in the outliner window.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to achieve with the mirror modifier? Is the cylinder around the eye socket a separate object? You might bet a better answer by uploading a copy of your blendfile to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1043

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The mirror modifier has a center.  You need to place your model on the correct side of its origin. You may just create vertices on one side of the local origin. You only need model on one side ... the left or the right.  There are more flexible alternatives than this but this is the good way to start.

In the image lets assume I am trying to make a sphere with just half a sphere. The blue sphere is almost correct.  I wanted the separation to be a little obvious visually for purposes of explanation.

The next attempt is where the model has too much separation.

In the last model I have unfortunately placed vertices on both sides of the X axis.  This may be what you did also.

You can either remove the mirror modifier. Or make a selection on the undesired vertices and grow the selection with Control+, then delete the vertices.

I wonder if you are seeing another mesh in the same place as the bird.  I suggest you change the names of the mesh to something like Bird so as to explain the issue better.

Comment: Hello. I want to mirror only the eye socket,but I see that when I select the mirror modifier the whole bird is mirrored. I'm in edit mode and the cylinder around the eye is not a separate object.

Comment: I need to mirror the eye socket from the left side to the right one. can you help me ? here you can find the blend file : http://psychonews.it/dati/Pierino0.blend